# How are web APIs handled in the browser?

Tags: browser, webapi, event-loop

While studying the JavaScript event loop, many materials showed that web APIs (setInterval, DOM event, etc.) are processed in the browser and are processed multi-threaded rather than single-threaded. I was able to confirm the contents.
I wanted to know more, so I looked for it, but I couldn't get any related information anywhere.
Is it true that web APIs are processed in parallel in multi-threaded form?

And asynchronous work is performed using a timer thread in Timer API, a type of Web API. Likewise, network-related APIs such as XMLHttpRequest and fetch are said to use network threads to process network requests and responses. I would like to check whether this is true with related official documentation.
Where can I find related topics?
Please note that it is not even listed in Google's official documentation.

I have been looking into how web apis are processed and would like to know how they are processed (single-threaded or multi-threaded).

Comment: That's very broad and implementation details. The only thing that the specs ask for is that some operations are ran ["in parallel"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#parallelism), but they don't define how this parallelism is achieved. Chromium has [some design docs](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/threading_and_tasks.md) about it, (and [about network requests](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/multi-process-resource-loading/)) but I believe a lot of it is already outdated. As a web dev this shouldn't matter to you anyway.

Comment: (...) Just know that some operations are ran asynchronously and won't block your code's execution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and kind response.
So, in conclusion, can we understand that web APIs in browsers are processed in parallel with multithreads?
And does the fact that some web APIs run asynchronously mean that other web APIs are processed synchronously rather than asynchronously?

Comment: No you can't conclude that in general. Only some implementations will use multi-threading. And yes, a lot of Web APIs operations are synchronous, e.g. most DOM methods are.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing the information. It was very helpful!! I wonder how you came across this knowledge.